# Get return value from pressed button

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a form that pops up at a specific event. It draws up buttons from an array and sets the Tag value to a specific value. So if you are to press or click this button the function should return the Tag value.

How can I do this? And how do I know which button was clicked?
At this moment the code returns DialogResult, but I want to return the Tag value from the function. How shall I modify my code so that it can do this?

```
public static DialogResult SelectBox(string title, string[] btnArray, string[] btnValueArray)
{
    Form form = new Form();

    Button[] buttonArray;
    buttonArray = new Button[5];

    form.Text = title;

    for (int i = 0; i < btnArray.Length; i++)
    {
        buttonArray[i] = new Button();
        buttonArray[i].Text = btnArray[i];
        buttonArray[i].Tag = new int();
        buttonArray[i].Tag = btnValueArray[i];

        buttonArray[i].TabStop = false;
        buttonArray[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, i * 40);
        buttonArray[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 40);
    }

    form.ClientSize = new Size(240, 268);
    form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { buttonArray[0], buttonArray[1], buttonArray[2] });
    form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    form.MinimizeBox = false;
    form.MaximizeBox = false;

    DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();
    return dialogResult;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a private variable in the form:

```
private object SelectedTag;
```

Add a button click handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SelectedTag = ((Button)sender).Tag;
}
```

Assign the handler to each button you create:

```
..
buttonArray[i].OnClick += form.Button_Click;
..
```

Then in your static function, simply return `form.SelectedTag` instead of the dialogresult.

Answer (score 2):

You could call the same click event for all buttons. then in your handler:

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  Button oButton = (Button) sender;

  object data = oButton.Tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DialogResult` property already tells you which button was clicked. You can set each individual button to return a different `DialogResult`, and then check for that at the bottom of the function.

And if you want to return the clicked button's `Tag` property instead, you need to change the function's return value to `Object` (because the `Tag` property is of type `Object`).

Comment: What if there are more than 8 buttons? (DialogResult enum has 8 possible values)

Comment: @Oscar: Yeah, if that's the case, you'll need to do a bit more work. Rarely (if ever) should a form contain more than 8 buttons.

Comment: Just open Microsoft Outlook, Go to Tools > Options and you will see (only in the first tab) 13 ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ButtonClick event handler in a TestForm, set the button's tag to the Form's tag.
Here is the sample.

Main Form:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Object tag;
            SelectBox("test", new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" }, new String[] {"one value", "Two value", "three value" }, out tag);
            MessageBox.Show(tag.ToString());
        }

        public static DialogResult SelectBox(string title, string[] btnArray, string[] btnValueArray, out Object tagValue)
        {
            TestForm form = new TestForm();

            Button[] buttonArray;
            buttonArray = new Button[5];

            form.Text = title;

            for (int i = 0; i < btnArray.Length; i++)
            {
                buttonArray[i] = new Button();
                buttonArray[i].Text = btnArray[i];
                buttonArray[i].Tag = new int();
                buttonArray[i].Tag = btnValueArray[i];

                buttonArray[i].TabStop = false;
                buttonArray[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, i * 40);
                buttonArray[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 40);
                // subscribe to button click event..
                // the handler is in TestForm
                buttonArray[i].Click += form.HandleOnButtonClick;
            }

            form.ClientSize = new Size(240, 268);
            form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { buttonArray[0], buttonArray[1], buttonArray[2] });
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            form.MinimizeBox = false;
            form.MaximizeBox = false;

            DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();
            // set the out args value
            tagValue = form.Tag;

            return dialogResult;
        }
```

TestForm that whose instance  we create in the SelectBox dialog:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }      

        public void HandleOnButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;

            if (button != null)
                this.Tag = button.Tag;
        }
    }
```

Edit:

If you want to capture every button's value then expose a `Dictionary<String, Object>` Tags property.