# How to cast buttons

Tags: c#, casting

I have some problems with the understanding of casting buttons, maybe you can help me. If i have for example 3 buttons and i wont have very long code i can cast them, right?
For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

If i give evry button a tag, i sould be able to ask if the button was clicked, right?

```
private void MachMalClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myButton = (Button)sender;

    if (myButton != null)
    {
        var test = myButton.Tag;
switch (test)
            {
                case 1: MessageBox.Show("button 1 was clicked");
                    break;
                case 2: MessageBox.Show("button 2 was clicked");
                    break;
                case 3: MessageBox.Show("button 3 was clicked");
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

if the upper mthode is succesful the object has to be a button (casted sender into button -> must be a button) But now i have problems to adress the tag. Can somebody help me? I dont find something on the internet and i´m sorry if this is a stupid question, but im new to c#.

Comment: "But now i have problems to adress the tag" - what is the problem?  Do you have an exception?  Please be more specific.

Comment: I cant do the switch, what makes me think that i have a thinking mistake in my brain. The error is a switch expression:   there must be a corresponding type that allows null values

Comment: This can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791645/get-return-value-from-pressed-button

Comment: Thanks very much, good link. I searched for over 30 mins and dont find anything what was really usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `Id property`

```
Button myButton = (Button)sender;
if(myButton.Id == "button1")
{
  ....
}
elseif(myButton.Id == "button2")
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you user1676819

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = myButton.Tag as string;
```

You cannot switch on an object.

Comment: Also a very big thanks to you. This is also very usefull for me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "Tag" property for this?

You can check against the Button objects directly.

```
if(sender == button1)
    MessageBox.Show("button 1 was clicked");
else if(sender == button2)
    MessageBox.Show("button 2 was clicked");
else if (...)
    ...
```

This assumes that the buttons are created design time and that the button fields are named "button1", "button2", etc.